# C# Conflicts with the declaration

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written this `Employee` class using C# winforms where `Employee` is promoted if `Employee.Experience >=5`.

I am getting an error on the line:
`Employee.PromoteEmployee(empList,employee=>employee.Experience>=5);`

> conflicts with the declaration Delegateusage01.Employee

I have read an article on MSDN and few others on Stackoverflow on this topic but I just can not find that error.

```
namespace DelegateUsage01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateNewEmployee(new Employee() { Id = 101, Experience = 5, Name = "Peter", Salary = 4000 });
            CreateNewEmployee(new Employee() { Id = 100, Experience = 5, Name = "Peter", Salary = 4000 });
        }

        private static void CreateNewEmployee(Employee emp)
        {
            int index = empList.FindIndex(Employee => Employee.Id == emp.Id);
            if (index != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Two id can not be the same");
            }
            else
            {
                empList.Add(emp);
            }
            Employee.PromoteEmployee(empList,employee=>employee.Experience>=5);
            //getting error on this line
        }
    }

    delegate bool IsPromotable(Employee empl );

    class Employee
    {
        private int _id;
        private int _salary;
        private string _name;
        private int _experience;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                if (value <= 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("ID can not be null");
                }
                _id = value;
            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value == String.Empty)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Name can not be empty");   
                }
                _name = value;
            }
        }

        public int Salary
        {
            get { return _salary; }
            set
            {
                if(value<=0)
                { throw  new Exception("Salary cannot be negative");}

                _salary = value;
            }
        }

        public int Experience
        {
            get { return _experience; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Experience can not be negative");
                }
                _experience = value;
            }
        }

        public static void PromoteEmployee(List<Employee> employeeList,IsPromotable IsEligibleToPromote)
        {
            foreach (var employee in employeeList)
            {
                if (IsEligibleToPromote(employee))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Employee: {0} with employee id: {1} is eligible for promotion", employee.Name, employee.Id);
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the line that you call FindIndex from List, you cannot use the name Employee there, use this instead :

```
  int index = empList.FindIndex(e => e.Id == emp.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your method signature from

```
PromoteEmployee(empList,employee=>employee.Experience>=5)
```

to the following

```
PromoteEmployee(empList,Func<Employee,bool>);
```

then you call

```
Employee.PromoteEmployee(empList,employee=>employee.Experience>=5);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Why do you suggest I should use Func<Employee,bool>  What is the difference?

Comment: Dear friend its generic delegates you can pass any logic to it like if you  dont want to hard code your implementation then you can use it like in you scenario you pass your employee type then in calling code you can do any thing you want. like as you do comparing

Comment: and one thing more please mark as answer if its helpful for you :D

Answer (score 0):

Drop the delegate alltogether, that's obsolete .NET 1.0 stuff.

Your function should take a `Func<Employee,bool>` instead. That should compile.

Comment: Actually Func was only added in 3.5, but Predicate<T> is a good alternative for 2.0 or 3.0.